# Get All Emails from a Outlook Folder by use of VBA Script

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to get all emails from "Inbox" folder from several mailboxes "Mailbox1", "Mailbox2" etc. and write the data into an array. Unfortunatelly my VBA script **does not indicate all emails**. I have permanent differences. E. g. in the "Mailbox1" within "Inbox" folder are saved 110 emails, but script indicates only 92.

I am using the following VBA script.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetAllIndicatedEmails()
    Dim MailboxnamesToIterate As Variant
    MailboxnamesToIterate = Array("Mailbox1", "Mailbox2") '...add more mailbox names
    
    Dim AllIndicatedEmails As Collection
    Set AllIndicatedEmails = New Collection
    
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMailbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set olNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    For i = LBound(MailboxnamesToIterate) To UBound(MailboxnamesToIterate)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set olMailbox = olNamespace.Folders(MailboxnamesToIterate(i))
        Set olInbox = olMailbox.Folders("Inbox")
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If Not olInbox Is Nothing Then
            Dim olItems As Outlook.items
            Set olItems = olInbox.items
            'olItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True
            
            ' Force Outlook to load all items
            Dim olTable As Outlook.Table
            Set olTable = olInbox.GetTable("")
            Do Until olTable.EndOfTable
                olTable.GetNextRow
            Loop
            
            Dim itemValues As Object
            Set itemValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            
            Dim count As Long
            count = 0
            
            For Each olItem In olItems
                If TypeName(olItem) = "MailItem" Or TypeName(olItem) = "AppointmentItem" Or TypeName(olItem) = "ContactItem" Then
                    count = count + 1
                    
                    Dim key As String
                    key = olItem.subject & "_" & olItem.Sender & "_" & Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                    
                    If Not itemValues.Exists(key) Then
                        itemValues.Add key, True
                        
                        Dim emailInfo(0 To 3) As Variant
                        emailInfo(0) = MailboxnamesToIterate(i)
                        emailInfo(1) = olInbox.name
                        emailInfo(2) = Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                        emailInfo(3) = olItem.subject
                        AllIndicatedEmails.Add emailInfo
                    End If
                End If
            Next olItem
            
            Debug.Print "Processed " & count & " items in " & MailboxnamesToIterate(i) & " - " & olInbox.name
        End If
    Next i

    ' Save the collection to a text file
    Dim fileSystem As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim currentDate As String
    Dim arrayString As String
    Dim emailData As Variant
    
    currentDate = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    
    Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fileSystem.CreateTextFile("C:\AAA_Work_Data\Statistic\IndicatedEmails_" & currentDate & ".txt")
    
For Each emailData In AllIndicatedEmails
    arrayString = Join(emailData, vbTab) ' Separate elements with Tab character
    file.WriteLine arrayString
Next emailData

' Close the file and clean up
file.Close
Set file = Nothing
Set fileSystem = Nothing

MsgBox "All indicated emails have been saved to C:\IndicatedEmails_" & currentDate & ".txt", vbInformation, "Export Complete"

Debug.Print "Found " & AllIndicatedEmails.count & " unique items."
End Sub
```

I checked many ressources in web in order to find a reason for the differences. The following points have been checked: 1. Changes within a folder during the script is running (NO) 2. Hidden items (NO) 3. Items with diifferent types (No, all are email messages).

Comment: Count the Else branch of `If TypeName(olItem) = "MailItem" Or TypeName(olItem) = "AppointmentItem" Or TypeName(olItem) = "ContactItem" Then`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Create an Else branch for `If TypeName(olItem) = "MailItem" Or TypeName(olItem) = "AppointmentItem" Or TypeName(olItem) = "ContactItem" Then` to count other types of items. `otherTypeCount = otherTypeCount + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Outlook may contain only the cached part of data - for a year, six months, three months, months and etc. So, when you iterate over all items in the folder you may deal with a cached data while the Exchange server may contain old items  (not cached locally).

Note, in the code you iterate over all three types of items in Outlook:

```
If TypeName(olItem) = "MailItem" Or TypeName(olItem) = "AppointmentItem" Or TypeName(olItem) = "ContactItem" Then
    count = count + 1
End If
```

With the current code the counter will not display all items number in the folder by default, for examples, notes, documents, reports are excluded. So, it makes sense to count ALL items without checking their types.

Finally, to confirm that the Outlook object model gives correct results you may try to use any low-level tools such as [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or *OutlookSpy*.

---

In the code you iterate over mailboxes by using its names:

```
MailboxnamesToIterate = Array("Mailbox1", "Mailbox2") '...add more mailbox names
```

That is not quite correct approach. You need to use the `Stores` collection, see the corresponding property of the `Namespace` class which returns a `Stores` collection object that represents all the Store objects in the current profile. Use the `Stores` and `Store` objects to enumerate all folders and search folders on all stores in the current session.

To get the `Inbox` folder from the store you need to use the [Store.GetDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.store.getdefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the default folder in the store and that is of the type specified by the `FolderType` argument.

This method is similar to the `GetDefaultFolder` method of the `NameSpace` object. The difference is that this method gets the default folder on the delivery store that is associated with the account, whereas `NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder` returns the default folder on the default store for the current profile.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for feedback, A. The folder "Inbox" is cleared manually every day. That means, we do not have any "old" emails which are 1,2,3 months old. The emails are maximum 2 days old. Unfortunatelly we may not use any low-level tools due to the restrictions. Do you see any possibility to indicate the emails by a VBA script? B. Is any possibility to realize it via MS Access? Maybe it would provide the necessary solution?

Comment: Nope. You could use low-level tools/applications just to confirm that you get correct results via the Outlook object model.

Comment: Can you please explain for me just in few sentences how it work with cache in Outlook? I see at the user interface within Outlook in the folder "Inbox" 5 emails dated  22.03.2023 (yesterday). That means the local application retrieved 5 email items from server an cached them locally. So far so good. As soon I try to get the emails from "Inbox" by VBA, the script indicates only 3 emails. What is wrong? The data about 5 items is available at the server as well as locally.

Comment: Try to count items without checking their types.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Inbox contains item other than `MailItem`, `AppointmentItem` and `ContactItem` that you expect. Inbox is very likely to also contain `ReportItem` and `MeetingItem` items, but it never contains `AppointmentItem` and `ContactItem` items.

You might want to log the item types you do not process

```
    For Each olItem In olItems
      typeName = TypeName(olItem)
      If typeName = "MailItem" Or typeName = "AppointmentItem" Or typeName = "ContactItem" Then
        ...
      Else
        Debug.Print "Unexpected item type: " & typeName
      End If
```